# "new" as an action name in Play

Tags: scala, rest, playframework, restful-architecture, playframework-2.2

Being reserved in JVM as a keyword, `new` should be escaped with 2 single back  quote signs to be used in Play as a name of an action (**new**, create, edit, update, index, delete, show). I think it causes inconvenience.

Is there another de-facto action name in Play to replace `new`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Play you can use any (not reserved in language) name for action, so it can be for an example `newItem`. It will be clear if in one controller you'll want to add actions for all models ie: `newPost`, `editPost`, `newComment`, `editComment`, etc.

If you'll use separate controllers for each model (which is better) you can also add an `Action` suffix to your actions `newAction`, `editAction` etc. Although seems redundant finally it's easier to use it later with implicit imports to differ ie. `indexAction` from `indexView`.

**P.S.** My favorite name for this action is `add` - but as you can see it's rather matter of taste not pattern.

Comment: of course, add! if case of newPost, I would have to use for other 6 actions: createPost, editPost, updatePost, showPost, deletePost. That seems too much redundant.

Comment: it turned out it is not even allowed to name a view as "new.scala.html"

Comment: By the way in many cases you can use the same view for `add` and `edit` actions ie `edit.scala.html`, just in first case fill the form with new, unsaved object (can also set some initial values to it), in second use form filled with persisted object.

Comment: My favorite name for this action is `create`, like in CRUD (Create, Read, Update, Delte), but yes, it's matter of taste ^^